# rebuilding columns and adding a new dataset to DataListView

Tags: c#, objectlistview

So I am using the DataListView variant from BrightIdeasSoftware for my c# project.

I use buttons to change the view of the DataListView. When a button is pressed the following is executed:

```
olv.DataSource = null;

olv.AllColumns = colList;
olv.RebuildColumns();

//Fill OLV with data
olv.DataSource = dt;
```

The first button creates 1 column and changes the view to View.Tile;.

The second button creates 4 columns and changes the view to View.Details;.

The new columns are shown immediately but it takes about a second for the data to show up in the list. It takes even longer when I rebuild a larger amount of columns.

When I run my application it builds the view with 4 columns in View.Details instantly.
Only when I switch from the first button view to the second button view it hangs for a moment.

In debug mode I noticed that RebuildColumns() is the one that hangs. 
But if I leave olv.DataSource = dt; out, code after RebuildColumns() is executed immediatly.

Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it is not clear to me if the lists that you are switching between use the same `DataTable` (I assume that's the type of your `dt` object). If source is identical then you needn't add and remove columns, you can set `OLVColumn.IsVisible`. That's faster.

Second, setting `ObjectListView.DataSource = null` won't remove items from the list (you need `ObjectListView.ClearObjects` for that), but what that will do is invalidate the internal `DataSourceAdapter.CurrencyManager` which will block any item updates until `ObjectListView.DataSource` is specifically set again. Setting the data source will add items to your list (calls `ObjectListView.BuildList`) which might be expensive if your source is large.

In conclusion:

If you just switch between lists with shared datasource then:

```
foreach (var column in this.dataListView.AllColumns)
    column.IsVisible = true;
// call this only when tampering with columns
this.dataListView.RebuildColumns();
// if you need to add/remove items, same philosophy, partial instead of 
// complete update use filtering instead of DataSource reset
```

If lists do not have a common datasource and therefore columns totally differ, then it is a price you have to pay, rebuilding columns and items, but you could escape with a `TabControl` for instance. You could switch between lists without having to reset DataSource all the time. That should be a one time experience.